# Disallow Network Connections in IFrame

Tags: javascript, html, css, iframe, sandbox

I have a frame that looks like this: `<iframe srcdoc="*insert HTML here*"></iframe>`.

The frame may have some javascript in it and that's okay.

How could I prevent the contents of that frame from connecting to the network?

This includes:
 - Javascript's HTTP requests and WebSocket connections etc
 - Remote resources referenced in CSS
 - External files in the HTML code

Is there some kind of sandbox rule to disable remote connections or do I have to regex all of that out? If so, what should I watch out for when applying the regex?

Comment: It's not possible. There's no effective and reliable way to modify an iframe's behavior on the client side.

Comment: _"what should I watch out for when applying the regex?"_ - you should keep in mind that that is a rather impossible task, and almost every solution you come to that you feel comfortable with is highly likely to still be a security risk, if the srcdoc content comes from an untrusted source.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is currently no reliable way of accomplishing this.

The `sandbox` attribute cannot apply the type of restriction you are trying to apply here. A [Content-Security-Policy](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/CSP) can (with some difficulty), but there is currently no way of reliably applying such a policy to an `<iframe>` that has its contents set by the `srcdoc` attribute, as there is no way of simulating HTTP headers for such a document. Indeed, an iframe with `srcdoc` is simply treated as part of the page which embeds it, and inherits any Content-Security-Policy from that page!

The W3C draft specification "[Content Security Policy: Embedded Enforcement](https://w3c.github.io/webappsec-csp/embedded/#csp-attribute)" has proposed a `csp` attribute. In the future, this might be usable to apply restrictions to such a document.

In the meantime, however, you will probably need to serve this content through a sandbox domain, or rethink your design.